# Create trigger with subquery

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have table with players line-ups. And I want to create trigger which will not allow to insert more then 11 players in one line up.

Table has 3 columns. Id, IdLineup, IdPlayer.

My code:

```
create or replace
trigger maximum_hracu before insert on sestava for each row

begin
if inserting then
  if (select count(*) from hraje where hraje.id_sestava = :new.id_sestava) <= 11 then
    insert into hraje values(seq_hraje.nextval,:new.id_sestava,1);  
  end if;
end if;
end;
```

Comment: can you please make the question more clear. As to what error you are getting and any sample out put if you can provide?

Answer (score 0):

In PL/SQL always use INTO clause to assign a value.

Can you try using the below(not tested) :

```
Begin
select count(*)  INTO v_abc from hraje where hraje.id_sestava = :new.id_sestava
...
if (v_abc <= 11) Then
insert into hraje...
...
```